# Webrtc incoming stream volume

Tags: webrtc, peerjs

im having a trouble with editing incoming mediastream volume.

Im using mediastream-gain and peerjs. Editing local stream gain is ok:

```
$('#my-video').prop('src', URL.createObjectURL(stream));
window.localStream = stream;
var gain = new MediaStreamGainController(stream);
gain.off();
```

But when setting the same to incoming stream:

```
call.on('stream', function(stream){
var gain = new MediaStreamGainController(stream);
gain.off();
$('#their-video').prop('src', URL.createObjectURL(stream));
```

It does not work. What is the difference?

Comment: What browser are you doing this in? If memory serves, one of the main stream browsers has an issue with remote media streams and attaching them to the AudioAPI(Chrome I think).

Answer (score 1):

Benjamin Trent is correct, it is a Chrome [issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=121673). `mediastream-gain` depends on WebAudio API and Chrome doesn't let WebAudio API hook-up with remote streams. I have been struggling with this for ages (for recording remote audio). I guess there is not much we can do about it, except star the issue and pray they care.

Comment: Yeah, From all that I read about that chrome bug over a year ago, it reads like a DESIGN issue and not just a bug...it sucks for sure.